# Кастомная сортировка

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Привет, 
Я писал тестовый фильтр который должен возвращать мне данные в ng-repeat

```
mainApp.filter('dateParser', function () {
    return function (param) {
        return [{id:1,day:'23.07.17'},{id:2,day:'22.07.17'}];
    };
});
```

когда я его вызываю

```
<td ng-repeat="crrDay in studentOne.daysList|dateParser">
        {{day.currentVal}}
</td>
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
```

Как я ее могу получать, если я возвращаю данные - константу?

*реальный фильтр, для которого и создан тестовый пример*

```
mainApp.filter('dateParser', function () {
    console.log(this);
    return function (param) {

        var parse, sorted, result = [], parsedArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
            parse = param[i].day.split('.');
            parsedArray[i] = {
                'id': param[i].id,
                'day': parse[0],
                'month': parse[1],
                'year': parse[2]
            };
        }
        sorted = _.sortBy(parsedArray, ['year', 'month', 'day']);
        for (i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            result[i] = {
                id:sorted[i].id,
                day: sorted[i].day + '.' + sorted[i].month + '.' + sorted[i].year
            };
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: ``<td ng-repeat="crrDay in studentOne.daysList|dateParser">
        {{day.currentVal}}
</td>``
В этом контексте, что есть ``day``? Если уж на то пошло, то вызывать надо ``{{crrDay.day}}``

Comment: @SergeyRogachev
так и должно быть. Это обращение к контроллеру.

Comment: Сделайте тогда нормальный воспроизводимый пример.